# Possible to use datetime.strptime() with month and year only?

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I have a list of dates that only have month and year values, like "May 2001", "March 2003". Is it possible to use `strptime` in Python to create `datetime` objects from these? It is acceptable if I assume the day value == 1, example: assume "May 2003" will correspond to "2003-05-01".

What would the method look like that does this?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail) says "For the `datetime.strptime()` class method, the default value is 1900-01-01T00:00:00.000: **any components not specified in the format string will be pulled from the default value**." (emphasis mine.) If often helps to RTF — or even to just try it to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

v = "May 2005"

date_obj = datetime.strptime(v, '%B %Y')
```